# How to load any number of images onto canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

How do i load any number of images onto the canvas. The number can be 5,6... how can i do that.So far i am only able to load 2 images but this code will not work for dynamic number of images.The code should be such that it should load many images.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
        function loadImages(sources, callback) {
            var images = {};
            var loadedImages = 0;
            var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(var src in sources) {
        numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
        images[src] = new Image();
        images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                callback(images);
            }
        };
        images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//var availableTags = <?php  echo json_encode($img_arr1) ?>;

var sources = {
    darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
    yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'

};

loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 100, 30, 200, 137);
    context.drawImage(images.yoda, 350, 55, 93, 104);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`for...in...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: The user will enter any number then accordingly the images will be loaded  eg the user will enter 5 then 5 images will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Save relevant data as list of objects and loop through them:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//var availableTags = <?php  echo json_encode($img_arr1) ?>;
var sourceSets = [];
var sources = {};
//Draw function
function draw() {
 //Clear board
 context.clearRect(-10, -10, 4000, 4000);
 //Loop through images and draw each one
 for (var i = 0; i < sourceSets.length; i++) {
  context.drawImage(sourceSets[i].img, sourceSets[i].x, sourceSets[i].y, sourceSets[i].w, sourceSets[i].h);
 }
}

function loadSource(src, x, y, w, h) {
 //Setting defaults
 if (src === void 0) {
  src = '';
 }
 if (x === void 0) {
  x = 0;
 }
 if (y === void 0) {
  y = 0;
 }
 if (w === void 0) {
  w = 100;
 }
 if (h === void 0) {
  h = 100;
 }
 //Creating image and loading from src
 if(sources[src] === void 0) {
  sources[src] = new Image();
  sources[src].onload = function () {
   draw();
  };
  sources[src].src = src;
 }
 var img = sources[src];
 img.src = src;
 //Save all relevant data in an object
 sourceSets.push({
  src : src,
  x : x,
  y : y,
  w : w,
  h : h,
  img : img
 });
}
//Add whatever amount of images here
var amount = parseInt(prompt("amount",4));
for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
 if(i%2 === 0) {
  loadSource('http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg', Math.random() * 400, Math.random() * 400, 200, 137);
 } else {
  loadSource('http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg', Math.random() * 400, Math.random() * 400, 93, 104);
 }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="540"></canvas>
```

Comment: If i have an array of images .? like  var availableTags = <?php  echo json_encode($img_arr1) ?>; Then how do i load the images

Comment: Depends on how an item in `$img_arr1` looks.

Comment: I have a json array.Containing images

Comment: `foreach($img_arr1 as $img){ echo 'loadSource("' . $img . '"); '; }`